# Infer year from incomplete date

Tags: mysql, datetime, awk

I'm parsing the output from a command, which produces date entries of the form `Mon 2/5 16:36`, and loading it into mysql.  Currently, `awk` is parsing the lines and preparing the data for `INSERT`ion. I would ideally like to use the `STR_TO_DATE` function, or a similar one, to generate myself a timestamp.

However, that function doesn't work without a year.  I cannot convince the command that is producing this date to give me a year, although I do know that it will never produce a date in the future.  I'm not exactly sure what happens if a date is >1 year old, because I've never seen that happen.  Thus, I would like the year to be the newest year such that the date is valid, but is not newer than `NOW()`.

Is there a way of doing this in pure SQL?

Some examples, resolved as if it is Feb 5, 2018 at 17:00:

- Sun 2/4 16:42 --> 2018-02-04
- Mon 2/5 16:59 --> 2018-02-05
- Mon 2/5 17:01 --> 2007-02-05
- Tue 2/6 08:00 --> 2007-02-06
- Mon 2/6 16:59 --> 2017-02-06

Comment: Is `2/5` Feb 5 or May 2?

Comment: The newest year? You mean the current year? You want to parse that terrible date output and stick the current year in there?

Comment: Specify your requirement better please. [Edit] your question. Suppose it's 17:00 on 5-Feb-2018.  Further suppose that 2/5 means 5-Feb.  If you get asked to handle this date string `Tue 2/6 08:00` do you want a DATETIME value of `2017-02-06 08:00` ? What about the date string `Sun 2/4 16:42`? What about `Mon 2/5 16:42`? What about `Mon 2/5 17:42`.  Once you understand your requirement with precision, it's not hard to use MySQL date arithmetic to implement it. What if the weekday doesn't match the date?

Comment: @O.Jones: You have correctly divined my intentions, but I added a few examples that should make it more clear.  Note that (as far as I know) any weekday will match with a date for *some* year.  Sat Feb 29 will resolve to 1992 (until 2018 becomes valid), but I believe there should always be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('Sun 2/4 16:42', YEAR(NOW())), '%a %c/%e %H:%i%Y') AS datetime;
+---------------------+
| datetime            |
+---------------------+
| 2018-02-04 16:42:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Then just test if the resulting `datetime > NOW()` and if so, recalculate:

```
mysql> SELECT @datetime - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AS datetime;
+---------------------+
| datetime            |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-04 16:42:00 |
+---------------------+
```